# ActiveX in OOB Silverlight5 app

Tags: silverlight, com, activex, silverlight-oob

I'm trying to use an ActiveX control in an out-of-browser Silverlight5 application.

This code (for in-browser) works:

Host Html page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetAXObjectStatus() {
            var axObject = document.getElementById("axObject");
            return axObject != null ? axObject.GetStatus() : -1;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <object id="axObject" classid="CLSID:my-cls-id"></object>
```

Silverlight:

```
string result = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("GetAXObjectStatus").ToString(); // works fine
```

But the following (for out-of-borwser), which is my goal, doesn't work:

```
// Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions == true
// AutomationFactory.IsAvailable == true
dynamic axObject = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("my_prog_id"); // returns a non-null object
axObject.GetStatus(); // produces a "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"
```

Any idea what might be wrong?